# Fetch nested data from Internet

Tags: flutter

**How to fetch nested json response ?** I can fetch direct value but cant fetch nested values

```
{
 "username":"aa",
 "data":{
          "key":"value",
          "anotherKey":"anotherValue"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first decode your json like this-

```
var respBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Then you can use `respBody["data"]["key"]`